# Jekyll and Disqus: cannot get disqus to appear on site

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, disqus

I am using Github Pages' Jekyll integration.  I added the Disqus configuration today but Disqus does not appear on my posts.  I have added the Disqus script to a file _includes/disqus.html and added {% include disqus.html %} to _layouts/default.html.

You may view this work at my https://github.com/shaneoston72/shaneoston72.github.io

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: I don't understand. Where is `{% if page.comments %}` and `{% endif %}` suppose to go? I only have markdown blog posts...I don't understand where that goes in my markdown...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, we'll need to do a few things here:

At the end of your file `_layouts/default.html` what I see is:

```
 </div>
    {% include disqus.html %}
    {% include footer.html %}   
  </body>
```

Replace this part for:

```
 </div>
    {% include footer.html %}
    {% if page.comments %}
    {% include disqus.html %}
    {% endif %}
  </body>
```

Then, on your file `_includes/disqus.html`, delete the first and the last line:

```
{% if post.comments %}
.....
{% endif %}
```

This should do the job. Let me know how it goes, ok?

Hope to have helped!