# Where does the Universal Embed Code go for Disqus and Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, disqus

I was going through the instructions of setting up Disqus but I don't understand where the Universal Embed code goes nor where `{% if page.comments %}` and `{% endif %}` is supposed to go.

I do understand where:

```
---
layout: default
comments: true
# other options
---
```

goes. At the top of my markdown (that is currently my blog post). I was also watching this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=154&v=Dr6pSdeJgkA

For how to manually install Disqus but I am still failing.

This is how my project looks like:

[image]

---

I saw this but wasn't helpful:

[Jekyll and Disqus: cannot get disqus to appear on site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35844744/jekyll-and-disqus-cannot-get-disqus-to-appear-on-site)

I also checked:

https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/where-does-the-universal-embed-code-go/3340

Quora:
https://www.quora.com/unanswered/Where-does-the-Universal-Embed-Code-go-for-Disqus-and-Jekyll

Their discuss page:
https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/where-does-the-universal-embed-code-go/3340/5

Answer (score 1):

As we have the file `disqus_comments.html` in the `_include` folder, this is where we have to paste the Universal Embed Code.

```html
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script>
  /**
   *  RECOMMENDED CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT AND UNCOMMENT
   *  THE SECTION BELOW TO INSERT DYNAMIC VALUES FROM YOUR
   *  PLATFORM OR CMS.
   *
   *  LEARN WHY DEFINING THESE VARIABLES IS IMPORTANT:
   *  https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/#configuration-variables
   */
  /*
    var disqus_config = function () {
        // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
        this.page.url = PAGE_URL;

        // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
        this.page.identifier = PAGE_IDENTIFIER;
    };
    */

  (function () {
    // REQUIRED CONFIGURATION VARIABLE: EDIT THE SHORTNAME BELOW
    var d = document,
      s = d.createElement('script');

    // IMPORTANT: Replace EXAMPLE with your forum shortname!
    s.src = 'https://EXAMPLE.disqus.com/embed.js';

    s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
    (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
  })();
</script>
<noscript>
  Please enable JavaScript to view the
  <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript" rel="nofollow"> comments powered by Disqus. </a>
</noscript>
```

In `https://EXAMPLE.disqus.com/embed.js`, replace `EXAMPLE` with our Disqus Username.

After making the Universal Code, we have to fetch that code in our post to render the comments, and to do so, we have to make a layout file of the post so create a file with the name `post.html` and put this code in it.

```html
---
comments: true
---

{% include disqus.html %}
```

Now make any post that will be a markdown file with code.

```markdown
---
layout: post
---
```

So, whenever we make a new post, we have only to repeat step 3. If still not working, try to check the `_config.yml` file for Disqus Username.

Comment: but I was reading from the disqus site that we also needed `comments: true` at the top too. Do we not?

Comment: is there an issue with which theme I use? do all themes work with discuss (using github pages)?